# What are alternatives to OpenSplice and RTI DDS implementations?

Tags: c#, data-distribution-service

I have a good amount of experience with RTI DDS and have used it in many applications. I have recently begun to use OpenSplice to work with DDS to see if there if it is a good open source alternative to RTI. I have had these two butting heads for a while now, trying to get messages to pass back and forth between different implementations to no avail.

What (if any) other DDS implementations would everyone recommend? I have found others such as OpenDDS but what I really want is a good DDS implementation that is compatible with RTI, supports C/C++/C#/Java, and is open source.

I realize OpenSplice fits this description but I want ones other than that. Thanks!

Comment: Well it looks like I have answered my own question. While there are other alternatives (such as OpenDDS) I ended up getting the RTI and OpenSplice application talking to each other just fine. So if you stumble across this thread looking for alternatives Prismtech's OpenSplice seems to be the way to go if you are trying to use DDS for free. RTI's implementation is better, cleaner, and more portable but they will charge you stacks of cash for it.

Comment: RTI have now released a open source community edition.  You no longer have to pay stacks of cash.  You just don't get the really useful tools that come with the non-community edition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the most recent OMG meeting, OpenDDS demonstrated inter-operability with both RTI and OpenSplice (among other DDS implementations).

Answer (score 3):

I first began trying the OCERA(see link below) C implementation of the RTPS (I even translated to C++) but it's just an RTPS v1.0 protocol implementation, not fully DDS compliant. Ironically, it's the first version of the protocol any DDS implementation should use to be compliant (with the interoperable protocol).

I'm sure you know the DDS vendors page, right?
http://portals.omg.org/dds/where-can-i-get-dds/

I have not tried the OpenSplice, but it's been used in many military applications (as well as the RTI), and it's open source (registered free :D)

The guys of the OpenDDS have a long tradition with OMG products. Inside some not interoperable OpenDDS transport is ACE (and maybe TAO, their efficient CORBA implementation). It's good to know they finally have the option of the interoperable protocol, damned!, where it was in 2008?

I wish it were any in C#!!!! ... that drove me to develop (open source) a C# publish/subscribe framework/middleware with **Google Protocol Buffers** as wired format, catching some ideas from DDS, JMS, TIBCO rendevouz and JGroups. If you are interest, just let me know (I'll be releasing the v2 very soon).

Answer (score 2):

There may be a very simple reason why OpenSplice DDS and RTI DDS did not communicate with each other, which is that you may not had configured OpenSplice to use DDSI as its wire-protocol.

OpenSplice DDS currently supports two protocols:

- DDSI, the DDS interoperability wire-protocol
- RT-NET, a proprietary protocol targeting hard real-time applications

Up to version 5.x OpenSplice DDS was configured to use RT-NET as the the default protocol. From v6.x we changed the default to use DDSI as the default.

Which version of OpenSplice DDS where you using?

That said, beware that OpenSplice DDS is Open Source and licensed under LGPL.

A+